# Java 17 and Yourkit 2021.11

Tags: java, docker, yourkit

Java 11 and yourkit 2020.9 working for me. Made upgrade to java 17 and yourkit 2021.11, yourkit not working for me.

Used this doc: https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/docker.jsp to add yourkit 2021.11 to docker but getting error when running it:

```
[YourKit Java Profiler 2021.11-b220] Log file: /home/kek/.yjp/log/test-8.log
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what():  No error information
```

How I can see what inside of `/home/kek/.yjp/log/test-8.log`or does java 17 and yourkit 2021.11 work for you?

Comment: It works for me without any issues. Are you sure you updated `libyjpagent.so` ?

Comment: this file exists inside of yourkit.zip under bin folder, should i copy it somewhere else?

Comment: `libyjpagent.so` is the only file that you have to deploy together with your application, it just has to be in such a location so that you can reference it  from run script. I.e if it's in `libs` directory you'd add `-agentpath:./libs/libyjpagent.so=port=<PORT>` to the param list when running java.

Comment: I did but getting error mentioned above

Comment: Then you'll have to check that log file. What do you mean by "How I can see what inside of ..." ? Do you mean, how to open file that is within the docker container? If you have access to that machine then you can run a bash command to get "inside" of container, i.e. `docker exec -it <container-name> bash`.

Comment: Appearently `yourkit 2021.11` should work on Java 17... I followed [Yourkit Profiling in Docker container](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/docker.jsp) instructions but I have the same issue here.

Comment: I meant that docker crashing with error and can't  get inside of the container to see what's inside, I thought if I can check what was inside of the file might give me some hints why it's happening

Comment: You can mount local directory to the path within container, so that everything that app in the container writes in there you could access outside of the container as well.

Comment: thanks, forgot about this option, will try

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that `azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:17-jre-headless` and `yourkit` not compatible, some library were not there for `yourkit`(didn't dig much), so by moving to `azul/zulu-openjdk-debian:17-jre-headless` fixed incompatibility for me.

Answer (score 1):

There might be problems with v2021.11 in musl-based Linuxes. Please use v2022.3 which has special profiling agent for musl https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/docker.jsp